# Is there a way to automate copying and insert copied cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Essentially I need to automate a simple process of copying rows and then inserting the copied rows. In Excel, I am highlighting the rows and then right clicking and hitting insert copied cells.

The data that I am copying is always in rows `127:138` and i want to copy it to row starting `143`.  It is important that I 'insert copy cells' as this would push the rows down, I want to do that as I will be running this macro over and over again so that eventually I end up with a list.

Comment: We are not a code writing service.

Comment: @Ramhound don't be too shortsighted. No VBA script capabilities are required here.

Comment: Welcome to Super User Clinton! I have edited your question because it was attracting close votes based on the request for code. If you aren't happy with the edit you can revert or [further edit it yourself](https://superuser.com/posts/1294925/edit). If LPChip's solution works for you, feel free to accept the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ beside the question :)

Answer (score 3):

Although you indeed need a macro for this, you forget that Excel has a build-in Macro recorder.

If the action you need to do is always the same, and there is no dynamic involved, you do not actually need to understand VBA to create this.

Simply find the Macro record button in the toolbar above, perform the actions you want to do from beginning to end, then hit the stop button.

You can then assign a keyboard shortcut to it, or even create a toolbar button and assign your macro to it. (or start the macro from the macro toolbar where you found the record button)

Comment: Good approach, +1 !

Answer (score 1):

*You use the below written VBA code to Copy specified Rows and move the Cell pointer to particular row to Paste copied Rows.*

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRows()

    Dim rngSource   As Range
    Dim rngTarget   As Range

    With Worksheets(1)
        Set rngSource = .Range("A127:A138")
        Set rngTarget = .Range("A143")

        rngSource.Copy

        rngTarget.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

**NB:** This code was tested by me before I've posted here.

*Hope this help you.*